# Jest: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am currently working on a big project and very new to JavaScript and Jest. The project is in React and I am trying to use jest to test these helper functions. The helper functions are in a file call inventory.js which is outside a few directories (client is the parent directory). I have looked at other solutions but can't find a simple solution.

I tried finding a simple solution and this was one that did not require Babel
My current `package.json` looks like the following:

```json
 {
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --trace-warnings' node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --detectOpenHandles"
}
```

[image]

The current file directory looks like the picture. The functions that need to be tested are in src/client/src/components/Inventory.js.